# oracle db 12c and odi 11g compatability

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm currently working with **O**racle **D**ata **I**ntegrator version 11g and Oracle **DB** version is also 11g and everything is working smooth but now I want to upgrade **Oracle DB** from **11g** to **12c** and I need to know whether compatibility between **oracle db 12c** and **odi 11g** exists or not? 
I search alot but got nothing useful related to my query. 
much appreciate your help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the [certification matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html) for ODI which is available on Oracle Technology Network.
If you repository is on the database you upgrade, make sure that version is supported in the certification matrix. It looks ok to upgrade to 12c if you are on ODI 11.1.1.7+.

You shouldn't have any problem with Oracle Database as a source or target in your ODI jobs, most of the things are backwards compatible, except maybe for Streams.